# Output negative values, regardless of original sign, on selected lines

Tags: text-processing

I am using the following code to read specific lines in an ASCII file "text.dat"

```
sed -n '/Columnaxis/p' text.dat
```

The output is

```
Columnaxis: 100
```

In order to output only the second part previous line, I added the following to the previous command line:

```
 sed -n '/Columnaxis/p' text.dat | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

The output of the last command is "100"

How can I update the last code to output negative numbers, regardless of the number's original sign? ( i.e if the input is "+100" I want the code to output "-100" also if the input is "-100", I want the code to output "-100"

PS. The content of text.dat is something like the following :

```
Columnaxis: 100
Columnaxis_1: 100
Columnaxis_2: -100
Columnaxis_3: 50
Columnaxis_4: -2.3
Columnaxis_5: 1.2
Columnaxis_6: -5
Columnaxis_7: -2
Columnaxis_8: -4
Columnaxis_9: -2
```

I want the code to output the following:

```
Columnaxis: -100
```

Let's say that the input has "Columnaxis: +100", then I want it to be

```
Columnaxis: -100
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input file and the output you want to see from it. For example, will the `+` be present or will positive numbers just no have a `-`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or `awk` alone:

```
$ cat text.dat
Columnaxis: 100
Columnaxis: +100
Columnaxis: -100

$ awk '/Columnaxis/ { gsub("-|+", "", $2); print "-"$2 }' text.dat
-100
-100
-100
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use arithmetic instead of string manipulation for this:

```
awk '
    function neg(x) {if (x<0) return x; else return -x}
    /Columnaxis/ {print neg($2)}
' file
```

works with values like "100" or "+100" or "-100" etc.

Comment: Sometimes regex isn't the answer (like prime numbers), +1

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `sed` alone:

```
sed -nE 's/^Columnaxis:[[:blank:]]+-?([0-9]+)$/-\1/p' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
Columnaxis: 100
Columnaxis: -100
asdklasjds

$ sed -nE 's/^Columnaxis:[[:blank:]]+-?([0-9]+)$/-\1/p' file.txt
-100
-100
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'Columnaxis:.*?\K\d+' file | sed 's/^/-/'
```

For example:

```
$ cat file 
Columnaxis: 100
Columnaxis: -5
$ grep -oP 'Columnaxis:.*?\K\d+' file | sed 's/^/-/'
-100
-5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed, replace with regex:
sed -E 's/[+-]?([0-9]+)$/-\1/g'

```
cat text.dat 
Columnaxis: 100
Columnaxis: +100
Columnaxis: -100

sed -E 's/[+-]?([0-9]+)$/-\1/g' text.dat 
Columnaxis: -100
Columnaxis: -100
Columnaxis: -100
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on [Glenn's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281056/116858), using the ternary conditional operator `?:`:

```
awk '{ print $1, ($2 > 0 ? -$2 : $2) }'
```

Testing it:

```
$ cat file.in
Columnaxis_0: 100
Columnaxis_1: +100
Columnaxis_2: -100

$ awk '{ print $1, ($2 > 0 ? -$2 : $2) }' file.in
Columnaxis_0: -100
Columnaxis_1: -100
Columnaxis_2: -100
```